# Bugsnag JS is making a request that Bugsnag Enterprise does not support

Tags: bugsnag

When making a standard bugsnag request to Bugsnag Enterprise, Chrome shows me that the request was rejected by the server with a 405 response status.

```
Request Method:GET
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
```

Here's my code:

```
const script_tag = document.createElement('script');
script_tag.setAttribute('src', '//d2wy8f7a9ursnm.cloudfront.net/bugsnag-3.min.js');
document.head.appendChild(script_tag);

script_tag.onload = () => {
  Bugsnag.apiKey = BUGSNAG_API_KEY;
  Bugsnag.endpoint = '//exceptions.my-domain.com';
  Bugsnag.notifyHandler = 'xhr';

  const e = new Error('Test error!');
  Bugsnag.notifyException(e);
}
```

(The reason I'm not using Bugsnag's `data` attributes like `data-apikey="..."` when inserting the tag is because that results in a warning from bugsnag: `[Bugsnag] Invalid API key 'undefined'`, but that's a separate issue...)

The [Bugsnag API docs](https://docs.bugsnag.com/api/error-reporting/) say that errors should be sent via POST requests, so I'm not sure why Bugsnag's own Javascript library would be making a GET request.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to append `/js` to the end of your notifier endpoint when reporting Javascript.

We use a GET request (instead of POST) for a few reasons, mainly to support errors from legacy browsers. That said, this may change in the future.

Let me know if that fixes the issue!

-Kelly@Bugsnag